# Can x-ms-webview be used in HTA (HTML Applications) in Windows 10?

Tags: javascript, windows, iframe, webview, hta

I have a number of older HTA (Microsoft HTML Application) applications that use iframes to display web content in some cases. As we all know, iframes (even in HTA's!) have become progressively more restrictive over the past years due to security issues like cross-domain access, etc. For example a simple URL like "http://www.google.com" used to render fine in an iframe (many ages ago!) but will no longer render in an iframe today.

Ideally I would like to change all my iframes (in my HTA's) to something like the x-ms-webview element but it is apparently not supported in the HTA (.hta) environment.

I still like HTA's as they allow full access to local filesystem read/writes in javascript, etc, so difficult to give up on them!

Does anyone know if there is a way to use the x-ms-webview tag in a Microsoft HTA?

Thanks!

Gerard